# How to express $f(x)$ as a power series

Tags: calculus, power-series, taylor-expansion

Is there any way to represent the function $f(x)= \displaystyle{x\over \sqrt[3]{8+4x^2}} $ as a power series centered at $0$ as $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}C_n x^n $ ?

More specifically, how can I find the $C_n $ of the power series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binomial series
$$(1+x)^a=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{a}{n}x^n$$
converges for $|x|<1$.  This is true for all real $a$, though you may only have seen it when $a$ is a positive integer.  If $a$ is not an integer the binomial coefficient has to be defined carefully as
$$\binom{a}{n}=\frac{a(a-1)(a-2)\cdots(a-(n-1))}{n!}\ .$$
You can find the series from this after rewriting your function as
$$f(x)=\frac12\,x\Bigl(1+\frac12\,x^2\Bigr)^{-1/3}\ ,$$
and the series will converge for $|x|<\sqrt2\,$.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the binom expansion
$$(1+y)^{-1/3}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty {-1/3 \choose k} y^k \,.$$
Next, set $y=x^2/2$ and multiply by $x/2$ to get
$$f(x)= \sum_{k=0}^\infty {-1/3 \choose k}2^{-k-1}  x^{2k+1} \,.$$